# How to search with the OR operator

Tags: discussion, search

I honestly thought you could use OR between any two search terms. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. You can only use OR between tags, is that right?

I was trying to find posts that are either tagged [xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml) or containing the word "xhtml", but searching for `[xhtml] or xhtml` gives only a handful of results.

So, how DO I search for posts that contain either a tag or a word? Or, one of two words?

Answer (score 7):

> Search for posts that contain either a tag or a word? Or, one of two words

Unfortunately, this is currently not supported.

> You can only use OR between tags

Yes, you are correct. OR works when used between tags.

Reference: [Is there now no logical “OR” operator with the new search engine?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163557/is-there-now-no-logical-or-operator-with-the-new-search-engine)